# Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception occured while processing the request

Tags: firebase, xamarin

> Unhandled Exception: Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception
>   occured while processing the request. Url:
>   https://mylimo-b2029.firebaseio.com/users/.json Request Data: 
>   Response: {"first_name":"dsadas"} occurred

`Mainpage.xaml.cs`:

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {

      base.OnAppearing();
       var allUsers = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
       lstPersons.ItemsSource = allUsers;
   }
```

`Firebasehelper.cs`:

```
public async Task<List<Users>> GetAllUsers()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("users")

          .OnceAsync<Users>()).Select(item => new Users
          {
              //user_id = item.Object.user_id,
              first_name = item.Object.first_name
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and decided to check if all properties are setting my local object. Just validating if the property is null, did not resolve.

Before:

```cs
var item = await firebase.Child("users").OnceAsync <Users> ());
```

Then:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var item = await firebase.Child("users").OnceAsync <JObject> ());
```

The problem is in the deserialization. You can access the properties in the JObject with:

```cs
var itemProperty = item.Object.GetValue("<property_name>").
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem, thank you!