# Can't Upload picture to firebase storage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get my user to pick a photo from the gallery (this code works works fine) then upload this picture to firebase storage. Once the code hits UploadPetProfileImage() the app enters breakpoint and I get the following error: : 'Exception occured while processing the request.

I'm unable to see what is wrong with code below:

FirebaseStorageHelper.cs

```
public async Task<string> UploadPetProfileImage(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
    {
        var imageUrl = await firebaseStorage
            .Child("PetProfileImages")
            .Child(fileName)
            .PutAsync(fileStream);
        return imageUrl;
    }
```

AddPetPage:

```
FirebaseStorageHelper firebaseStorageHelper = new FirebaseStorageHelper();
private async void AddPetImage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images,
            PickerTitle = "Pick an Image of your Dog!"
        });

        if(pickResult != null)
        {
            var stream = await pickResult.OpenReadAsync();
            PetImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            PetImageFileName = pickResult.FileName;
            AddPetImageBtn.IsVisible = false;

            await firebaseStorageHelper.UploadPetProfileImage(stream, pickResult.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this out, https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-working-with-firebase-storage

Comment: I was using this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-storage-crud-operations2/ by the same guy. However I don't see what I have done wrong

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56054361/199364

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue:

[image]

Please check the connection to your Firebase Storage.

Do not use the `gs://xamarinfirebasestorage-xxxxx.appspot.com`. Use `xamarinfirebasestorage-xxxxx.appspot.com` instead.

```
 FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage =  new FirebaseStorage("xamarinfirebasestorage-xxxxx.appspot.com");
```

[image]