# Xamarin Firebase.Database.FirebaseException

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add data to Firebase Realtime Database but i keep getting this error:

> Firebase.Database.FirebaseException   Message=Exception occured while
> processing the request. Url:
> https://databaseName.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/test/-Ms-WClXUQ9NiYItBJKv/.json?print=silent
> Request Data: {"className":"test"}

Code:

```
   private async void addClass_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://databaseName.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
        var i = await firebase
          .Child("test")
          .PostAsync(new Class1() { className = "test"});
    }
```

Firebase rules:

> {   "rules": {    ".read":true,
> ".write":true   } }

Model:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string className { get; set; }
}
```

UPDADTE:

I just tried to run it on an emulator and it worked so apparently there is something wrong with my physical phone.

Comment: Are you sure the device is connected to the internet? Does it have the same Configuration (Debug vs Release)? Are you testing the same platform for both (iOS v Android)?

Comment: How about the suggestion in the link below? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054361/firebase-database-firebaseexception-exception-occured-while-processing-the-requ Maybe it would  be helpful.