# Firebase exception while reading using FirebaseDatabase.net

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a particular object from firebase, but I get this exception:

```
public async void ReadByIdAsync(string ChildName, string Id) {

    var item = await firebaseClient
       .Child(ChildName)
       .Child(Id)
       .OnceAsync<NotebookNote>();

    var itemProperty = item.Count;

    System.Console.WriteLine(itemProperty);

}
```

> Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: 'Exception occured while processing the request.
> Url: https://duonotes-f2b77-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Notes/-
> MxgjxhpwoBeOLBy83rh/.json
> Request Data:
> Response: {"CreatedDate":"Wednesday, March 9,
> 2022","FileLocation":"https://notesbucket.blob.core.windows.net/notes/1.html","Name":"1","NotebookId":"-MxgjqZ9JShzHH21k_RS"}'

I already checked this solution, but it did not work in my case

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054361/firebase-database-firebaseexception-exception-occured-while-processing-the-requ?fbclid=IwAR0I4KT7ldUvAeP9gzjJvnJycHat4XOplBrIm-Atv8IiXUvV7T0JGwTpV18)

The strange part is that in the response, I am getting all the data that I want.

The thing that confuses me the most, is that I have a method that is almost the same, and works perfectly

```
public async Task<List<NotebookNote>> ReadWithOutUpdateAsync(string ChildName, string NotebookId = "") {
      
    var list = await firebaseClient.Child(ChildName)
         .OnceAsync<NotebookNote>();
   
    var collection = new List<NotebookNote>();
    foreach (var item in list) {
        NotebookNote notebookNote = null;
        notebookNote = Convert(ChildName, item);
        collection.Add(notebookNote);
    }
    if (ChildName.Equals(AppConstant.Notes)) {
        collection = collection.Where(n => ((Note)n).NotebookId == NotebookId).ToList();
    }
    return collection;
}
```

I even tried the example code in GitHub and I get the same exception (I modify it for my needs)

```
public async void ReadByIdAsync(string ChildName, string Id) {

    var Notes = await firebaseClient
                           .Child(ChildName).Child(Id)
                           .OnceAsync<NotebookNote>();

    foreach (var item in Notes) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ item.Key}");
    }
```

Comment: What happened when you used `OnceAsync<JObject>`? Did you still get the same error (which seems unlikely), or did something else go wrong then?

Comment: I fix it by doing ```  var Notes = await firebaseClient
                                   .Child(ChildName)
                                   .Child(Id)
                                   .OnceAsync<object>();

            var items = Notes.ToList();```
By the way when is google firebase GOING TO HAVE AN OFICIAL C#/XAMARIN FORMS LIBRARY